# Web Browser shows nothing when I execute my php code

Tags: php

I'm starting to learn php, but at the beginning I came across with an error which I don't know how to solve it. I have installed wampserver 2.4 in my windows 7. When I tried to execute a simple file containing only an echo, nothing appeared neither an error. 
What's the problem?

My code:

```
<?

echo "oi";

?>
```

Comment: Does your WampServer have short tags enabled?

Comment: I'd try `<?php` instead of the first `<?`

Comment: maybe short tags is disabled. try full code `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: where have you put your file. you need to execute code via localhost like: localhost/foldername/filename.php

Comment: write your link and output of the browser

Comment: It is always better to use <?php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably is that short open tag is not on.
Change it in php.ini
In the php.ini file you have to change is make sure that will be like that:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Also, try to use `<?php instead <?`

Also you can do it by wamp server, click on the wamp icon, go to PHP-> PHP Extensions -> open short tags

Comment: Your explanation was the best and was also the easiest to solve my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `php.ini` file you have no permission to use short tag

change it

from `short_open_tag = Off`
to    `short_open_tag = On`

or use full tag

```
<?php //full php tag

echo "oi";

?>
```